# Civics: word for a representative's constituent who voted or will vote for them

Tags: vocabulary, politics, government

In the U.S. as an example, a senator represents constituents -- the people in her area of representation. What's a word or short term for those constituents who voted for her?

As a more concrete example, what political term could we use to describe the Californians who voted for and elected Nanci Pelosi, the Floridians who voted for and elected Marco Rubio, or the Connecticuters who voted for and elected Richard Blumenthal?

I'd be quite happy if such a term also included people who currently intended to vote in the next election for the politician in question.

Comment: They are **supporters**.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, but supporters don't have to be constituents. So I've been using "supporting constituents" but wish there were something better.

Comment: They can't vote for the candidate if they are not constituents, so it is clear from the context. Can you please supply an example use case? Such as "Thank you to all my supporters for electing me."

Comment: @WeatherVane Here's the sentence that got me wondering: "So if you're a senator and half of your supporting constituents believe Trump won in a landslide and another 40% are happy to play along, does constitutional hardball become a logical choice?"  Now maybe you're right and "supporters" is fine here given the context. But supporters can also be financial and so on?

Comment: Quotation should be in the question not a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Those who vote for the given candidate are the candidate's *Voters*. They are not voters for the opposition candidate but this candidate. The base refers just to those who have and always will always vote for them, i.e. habit + ignorance.  The candidate's voters are the ones, all of them, who voted for them this time. Whether they will next time is likely the issue you will be writing about.

One who has the privilege to vote is a *Suffragist* or enjoys *Suffrage*. The rest of us suffer after the vote.

Comment: Note that "voters" without an article could refer to the entire population eligible to vote, or who vote for anyone, so the possessive is usually needed. There might be a little ambiguity sometimes, but "Trump acted to reward his voters" is unambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Voters who mostly cling to one person or party would be called 'their base.'

Comment: *Base*, as nowadays used by political commentators, is a narrower term than what the OP has in mind. It refers to the loyal, committed, enthusiastic supporters (you yourself use the word *cling*), while the OP is seeking a term for everybody who voted for a particular politician.